# VBA Sum Range including Variant

Tags: vba, excel, inputbox

So I've defined myValue as an input value but now I want to sum the input value with the sum of F39:41.

```
Dim myValue As Variant

    myValue = InputBox("Enter Value", "Enter Value in £'s", "£")
    Range("B7").Formula = "=Sum(F39:F41)" + CInt(myValue)
```

Range("B7").Value = myValue works just fine, but if I look to also include sum F39:41 in the formula it fails. I've tried this as a formula with CInt but still not working. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to put a formula in the cell or a static value?

Comment: Formula to be included in the cell. Ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enter a formula you would use:

```
Range("B7").Formula = "=Sum(F39:F41)+" & CInt(myValue)
```

Comment: Thank you perfect. Such a simple solution :/

Answer (score 0):

I make it that you want:

```
Dim myValue As Variant

myValue = InputBox("Enter Value", "Enter Value in £'s", "£")
Range("B7").Formula = "=Sum(F39:F41)  +" & CInt(myValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

The value returned by InputBox is a string, so there's no need to convert to an Integer to add it to a formula. Moreover, you might want to check that the user didn't canceled the input:

```
Dim userInput As String
userInput = InputBox("Enter Value", "Enter Value in £'s", "£")
If Len(userInput) Then
  Range("B7").Formula = "=Sum(F39:F41)+" & userInput
End If
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Range("B7").Value = evaluate("=Sum(F39:F41)") + CInt(myValue)
```

Comment: This will add only a value, not a formula. Also no need for the equality sign in `Evaluate`.

Comment: @Vegard, since the OP's question is not clear about whether he/she needs the result or formula so the suggestions will vary because of unclear description.  Downvoting someones thread without clear understanding about the answer will be considered as an unclear downvoter.

Comment: The question was clarified in the comments below the question.

Comment: @Vegard, See the time of posting.

Comment: Quote: "(nor am I trying to take anything from you)" Downvoting someones post will reduce the reputation points.  If you find someones answer is correct upvote that post.  Don't be contradictory person without knowing how SO works. I personally upvoted Rory's post to +1 since it solves OP's expectation. Downvoting should be considered if the post is completely useless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106446/discussion-between-sixthsense-and-vegard).